# Got errors when trying to deploy cube

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssas, data-warehouse

I tried to deploy my cubes but got these error on visual studio 2012. Please help me as i am new and i dont understand what to do. Errors are listed below.

```
Internal error: The operation terminated unsuccessfully.

OLE DB error: OLE DB or ODBC error: Cannot open database "datawarehouse" requested by the login. The login failed.; 42000.

Errors in the high-level relational engine. A connection could not be made to the data source with the DataSourceID of 'Datawarehouse', Name of 'Datawarehouse'.
Errors in the OLAP storage engine: An error occurred while the dimension, with the ID of 'Customer', Name of 'Customer' was being processed.
Errors in the OLAP storage engine: An error occurred while the 'Cust Id' attribute of the 'Customer' dimension from the 'dwCube' database was being processed.

Server: The current operation was cancelled because another operation in the transaction failed.

OLE DB error: OLE DB or ODBC error: Cannot open database "datawarehouse" requested by the login. The login failed.; 42000.

Errors in the high-level relational engine. A connection could not be made to the data source with the DataSourceID of 'Datawarehouse', Name of 'Datawarehouse'.
Errors in the OLAP storage engine: An error occurred while the dimension, with the ID of 'Route', Name of 'Route' was being processed.
Errors in the OLAP storage engine: An error occurred while the 'Route Id' attribute of the 'Route' dimension from the 'dwCube' database was being processed.
```

Comment: It looks like, in the place where you're deploying the cube, it can't open the data warehouse database connection.

Comment: how can i open that connection please help me if u know any thing about this

Answer (score 3):

Please check if the connection for cube is available or not

1. Connect to your cube by SSMS
2. And find the cube datasource by expand CubeDataBase Folder->DataSouce Folder->DataSouce.

3.Double click the DataSouce and Open the Connectin String property window.

4.Type the valid cube server name, username and password.

5.Make sure succeed to test the connection.

6.Then try to process your cube manually.

MDXHelper : IDE to Write, Analyze, Tuning, Debug MDX efficiently